# 29 checkbox on a screen of a mobile app

Tags: mobile, checkboxes, multi-selection

I have a strange challenge of showing 29 multiple select options as part of a question which user needs to answer in a mobile web app for Android and iPhone.

Does anyone has had a similar problem and a solution to this?

The solution I am currently thinking of is to divide it into (3) carousal type screen which user can swipe between and select appropriate options.

Comment: Can the multiple select options be nested somehow? E.g. do certain of the multiple select options belong to the same category... Are all checkbox options applicable for all interaction flows in the form?

Comment: Thanks for your comment Andreas! I too would think of grouping or nesting them logically, however these options are distinct and not related.

Comment: This sounds more like a copy/content problem than something that UI should be expected to fix.

Answer (score 4):

29 options are too many to oversee, recall and choose from for a user - especially at mobile settings.

A solution could be to split the 29 into some logical groups. Either group of answers(and split the question into i.e. 3 steps) or questions (i.e. 3 questions instead of one for all).

Checkboxes are better to discover than caroussels, where you see only a part of all options - last 2 and coming 2. Thus I would go for Checkboxes.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with dividing the options into three screens is - you already pointed it out - that the options are not connected to each other.

Depending on the nature of the problem, you could still create a [Wizard-like](http://ui-patterns.com/patterns/Wizard) step-by-step navigation. Since you're using checkboxes (true or false) you could convert your current answers into Questions with "Yes" and "No" buttons for the answer.

In addition, I'd like to point out, that you should be *absolutely* sure if the it's really necessary for the user to answer all questions/see all options

Answer (score 1):

The user has to see *all* the options so they can choose those that are appropriate, right? I am assuming the following as ***I don't know the content***:

(1) Nesting or grouping won't make anything easier for the user.
 
(2) Nesting or grouping may be harmful and give you biased responses.
(3) The options are only text and short.

When there's a set of values that you can't explicit show on the screen because they are too many, you can create a modal window completely dedicated *to see and to choose one or more options*. It is recommended when there is a large set like yours.

The navigation, that consists in going through a set of questions, will momentarily be interrupted so the user can answer that specific complex question and then he will be back to the default flow. A modal is designed for that. It really fits your case.

Finally, this solution also works nice with the concept of a *web app*. 
The interface may look like this:

[image: Modal window for a large set of options]

After closing the modal window, consider giving the user a teaser that indicates that the question was answered.